# xrandr changes screen size but doesn't adjust it to physical screen

Tags: 22.04, screen, xrandr, gpu

I have ideapad slim5 amd ryzen 7700 and amd gpu, also I have 22 ubuntu. Some time ago my laptop started long shut downs and some logs appeared on boot. Logs were about virtualbox and failing to start apache server, but nothing really have changed yet, until one day `xrandr --output eDP --mode 1680x1050` didn't stretch to the full screen (I would notice this since this command is executed on every boot). I managed to get rid of the logs on boot and long shut downs are not longer the issue as well, but problem still remains. I can't even enter the part of the screen that in not rendered correctly.

on 2560x1600 screen is fully rendered.

[image of my laptop after executing `xrandr --output eDP --mode 1680x1050`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYqqB.jpg)

Also I should mention that I have a game which had 60fps or more always and now its 30fps on average. Because of this I checked if I had any gpu driver updates available but that was not the case as well. I am using lutris to run this game which makes its own wine prefix.

Update:
I installed whole ubuntu from the start (deleted everything while doing so). Even on my frashly installed ubuntu this is still the problem. I have lenovo ideapad slim 5 with amd cpu and gpu.

- CPU - AMD® Ryzen 7 7730u with radeon graphics × 16
- GPU - RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.54, 6.5.0-14-generic)

I saw there is a case of amd updating gpu drivers and that affects performance of a driver negatively. Could that be the case here? Can you suggest what can I try to solve this?